# Parse.com REST API Does Not Return Anything

Tags: android, http, parse-platform, response

I'm having a major issue and hope someone can help.

We have web and Android applications which use Parse as their backend. The issue we are having occurrs on both. I'll explain the Android issue.

We use the REST API to save data up to Parse.com. The reason we do not use the SDK is that we want to take advantage of the batch operation which is only available in the RESTAPI.

```
{
  "requests": [
    {
      "body": {
        "isFriable": false,
        "haDetail": "",
        "sizeOther": "",
        "colourOther": "",
        "texture": "",
        "fieldInspection": {
          "__type": "Pointer",
          "className": "FieldInspection",
          "objectId": "YS5bXHBwDu"
        },
        "surfaceSubType": {
          "__type": "Pointer",
          "className": "SurfaceSubType",
          "objectId": "d4IL5k1pv5"
        },
        "size": {
          "__type": "Pointer",
          "className": "HomogenousMaterialSize",
          "objectId": "ezr3uHDUvt"
        },
        "colour": {
          "__type": "Pointer",
          "className": "HomogenousMaterialColour",
          "objectId": "NqYXJcOkPE"
        }
      },
      "method": "POST",
      "path": "/1/classes/HomogenousArea"
    }
  ]
}
```

The above is my request. This gets pushed to https://api.parse.com/1/batch using a basic default HttpClient.

When we execute the HTTP request it sometimes just hangs, it does not return any result. Roughly one in every 5 or 6 requests does this. The exact same data on a subsequent request that succeeds will go through fine. The problem is that at that point we have duplicate records persisted to Parse as our sync logic never completed since we did not get a response.

Is there anything in Parse we can use to debug requests like this? Below is the current http client implementation we are using. NOTE: Also put in OkHttp from Square and hit the exact same issue.

```
        // Instantiate the http client to make the batch request
        DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpPost post = setupHttpPost(url);

        // Assign the data to the post
        StringEntity entity = new StringEntity(insertData);
        post.setEntity(entity);

        // Setup the response handler
        ResponseHandler response = new BasicResponseHandler();

        // Make the call to Post the new data
        Object rersponse = httpClient.execute(post, response);
        if (rersponse != null) {
            return rersponse.toString();    
        }
        return null;
```

Answer (score 0):

wierd behavior of the ./batch....

Make sure that you are NOT missing parse error responses. IMO - sometimes there may be JSON parse errors or something that can be missed if you are not paying close attention to the handler on the Entity in the http Response....

I have not used Parse batch api. I have used multithread http client and not seen prevalent timeout type issues that you mention?

Since you use REST, you should be able to wrap some test calls in CURL client that you can instrument with CURL CLI switches to provide more -debug ...

Since you use REST, you could switch from batch interface to a multi-threaded client, ( see the "threads" example, see "config" example at [org.apache](https://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/examples.html) ...

Wild guess but if you break down your batches maybe a background of higher number of Http EXEC's each with smaller payload may work out better????

The config example at the link shows how you can config the pool sizes by domain and how you can instrument the Timeouts ( conn timeout, req timeout etc ).

Comment: Thanks for the reply Robert. The outter calling method is wrapped in an AsyncTask so network operations don't block the UI thread. I've also cut down the amount of data going in a request and still the same. My next port of call is to send direct but I suspect I wont see any errors as its working itermittantly

Comment: i would drill the AsnycTask,, that's where your issue is.

Comment: I'm already following that path. Will let you know the outcome. Thanks again for quick responses